# MySQL Functions in WordPress Admin Page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently making a custom WordPress admin page via functions.php. I want this page to basically retrieve information from a SQL database (unrelated to WordPress) and display it to the visitor. I can do that fine, but if I stick the code for this in my functions.php, will that SQL code run pretty much on every page request, no matter what page? Here's my functions file pretty much:

```
function mytheme_add_admin() {
add_menu_page('Members', 'Members', 'moderate_comments', 'members', 'mytheme_admin');
}

function mytheme_admin() {
?>
#all the code for my page here
<?php }

add_action('admin_menu', 'mytheme_add_admin');
```

The "#all the code for my page here" would be HTML and bits of PHP to grab SQL data. Is there a way to make this only happen when viewing that specific admin page?

Answer (score 0):

This will run a query on every page load unless you add a condition either within the function itself or (preferably) around the add_action() call. There are several ways of having it run only on a single page, but the two easiest ways are probably to use wordpress' built in global variable 'pagenow' or to use one of the $_SERVER variables to do the same ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] for instance)

```
if (in_array($GLOBALS['pagenow'], array(pages this should show up on))){
   add_action('admin_menu', 'mytheme_add_admin');
}
```

or

```
if (in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], array(pages this should show up on with path from root))){
    add_action('admin_menu', 'mytheme_add_admin');
}
```